# MySQL Query returns no rows and no errors where phpMyAdmin returns 1 row in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely out of ideas as to what's happening here.

Here's my code:

```
    $sid = "123";
    $sid_query_conf = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE sid='$sid'");
if(!$sid_query_conf)
    die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sid_query_conf);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    die("Error processing your details");
```

It's consistently returning "Error processing your details" where is phpMyAdmin I get the result that I'm looking for. There's even 1 query before this so I know that the connection it works in that respect.

I've even tried to just select everything from the table and it's still returning no rows. mysql_fetch_result also did nothing.

I could really do with some help as to what's happening to make it not work like this.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but shouldn't there be a `;` at the end of `$sid = 123`? Thus, `$sid = 123;`

Comment: Then again, might even need quotes around `123`. `$sid = '123';` or `$sid = "123";` depending on the query.

Comment: @Fred, yes there needs to be a `;` at the end of the `$sid = 123` line

Comment: Sorry, 123 is a censor of the original. There is a semicolon and the value has already been determined at a string. Let me change that.

Comment: Semicolon isn't required.

Comment: Its okay @Rob, you will just want to make sure your code is **exactly** as you have shown it, or else we wont be able to help you very well.

Comment: Exactly. Even if it's not "the" actual coded line, a variant of a variable if I can say, can be anything.

Comment: @Barmar If the semi-colon isn't required, then how does one know if the variable is a string? Could it have been coded as `$sid = "123"`?

Comment: @Barmar, how do you figure?

Comment: @Fred Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were saying that a semicolon is required in the SQL. The question had been edited so the missing PHP semicolon was added.

Comment: @Barmar Not a problem. I knew there was one little wee thing that seemed outta whack. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `mysql_num_rows($result)` should be `mysql_num_rows($sid_query_conf)`

Also you shouldnt be using mysql_* functions anymore as they are deprecated, use PDO or mysqli instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Answer looks fine to me! +1

Comment: Yep, you got it. My bad. Also, I'll change the queries I have, I didn't know they were deprecated. Thanks!